# Please rename the [mongo-cxx] tag to [mongo-cxx-driver]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I'm one of the maintainers of the MongoDB C++ Driver: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver

There are currently 133 questions tagged [mongo-cxx]: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mongo-cxx/info

I'd prefer that the tag include the word "driver" to make it clear that the tag is for the driver, and not general C++ questions related to MongoDB - such questions could be handled with the tags [mongodb] and [c++]. Since it seems like a good idea for the tag name here to match the project name on GitHub, I'd like to see it renamed to [mongo-cxx-driver].

I don't currently have sufficient rights to make such an edit myself. If there is agreement on the above proposed renaming I would ask that a moderator with sufficient rights please do so on my behalf.

Comment: [tag:mongo-cxx] is pretty clear for me that it is related with the driver usage and not general c++ with mongo. The real problem would be if the tag was named as [tag:mongo-c++].

Comment: Several of the other drivers have tags that have -driver at the end: mongo-c-driver, mongo-java-driver, etc. It would be clearer if the C++ driver followed suit.

Comment: OK I'm puzzled. This has 36 votes and no strong arguments against. I flagged it for moderator attention. I believe it is tagged correctly. What else do I need to do to get this request attention?

Comment: Now I'm just sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there has been no opposition to this proposal for nearly a month, I've gone ahead and renamed the tag. The new tag is [mongo-cxx-driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongo-cxx-driver).

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!